# Generate Dynamic Css

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to generate a Css that will be the same for all my items execept for especific thing like color or image... I wonder if I can do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/styles.aspx?id=123">
```

Just for testing I try something simple like this:
ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm5ToCss.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm5ToCss" EnableViewState="false" %>
.aaa
{
    color: red;
}
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class WebForm5ToCss : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
//Get the ID, check database or files and change the style
        }
    }
```

but doesn't work for me. any ideas?
What I am doing instead is separating the smallest part of css that is different by items from the big style. "like" skeleton pattern  so I don't repeat myself. And maybe I continue doing that because of performance... but I want to know anyway how to do it in this other way.

Comment: content type should be text/css. Set CSS file for the page at OnInit event

Comment: Here the list complete of mime types: http://www.utoronto.ca/webdocs/HTMLdocs/Book/Book-3ed/appb/mimetype.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix it, but you should change your content type to `"text/css"`.